# In Chinese typesetting, is there a version of Lorem Ipsum?

Tags: characters, fonts

I know relatively little about typography but I know that Lorem Ipsum or other similar bodies of text appear a lot in the world of typesetting. Because Chinese characters are pretty much square, is there a need for a Chinese Lorem Ipsum? If so, what texts or series are used?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no standard text, but there is sometimes the need for something equivalent (i.e. a body of text to see how typesetting looks).  Sometimes this is referred to as 乱数假文.  Your exact question has been asked and answered in Chinese here: http://www.zhihu.com/question/19708165 , if you want to read more.  You can also find a tool for generating such texts here: http://www.richyli.com/tool/loremipsum/

Answer (score 1):

I would say that your guess is right. Since Chinese characters are all square (even for punctuations, in fact, punctuations are not commonly used until early 1900s), when typeset, they are all perfectly aligned, and there is no need to prepare something like Lorem Ipsum.